# How to install PHP enchant and pspell extension in heroku?

Tags: php, heroku, deployment, composer-php, php-extension

I'm trying to install PHP enchant and pspell extension in heroku [runtime](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/php-support) via composer but heroku default doesn't support pspell and enchant extension. you can see all list on their [Extensions Support List](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/php-support#extensions) page. So how do I install these extensions?

### Composer.php

```
"config": {
    "optimize-autoloader": true,
    "preferred-install": "dist",
    "sort-packages": true,
    "platform": {
        "ext-memcached": "1.5",
        "ext-imagick": "3.4",
        "ext-enchant": "7.2",
        "ext-pspell": "12.2"
    }
},
"require": {
    "php": "^7.2",
    "ext-ctype": "*",
    "ext-curl": "*",
    "ext-exif": "*",
    "ext-gd": "*",
    "ext-imagick": "*",
    "ext-json": "*",
    "ext-memcached": "*",
    "ext-openssl": "*",
    "ext-pdo": "*",
    "ext-pdo_mysql": "*",
    "ext-pgsql": "*",
    "ext-pdo_pgsql": "*",
    "ext-enchant": "^7.2",
    ......
},
```

### Heroku Deploy Error

```
-----> PHP app detected
-----> Bootstrapping...
-----> Installing platform packages...
 !     WARNING: A requested extension is not available
 !     ERROR: Failed to install system packages!
 !     
 !     Your platform requirements (for runtimes and extensions) could
 !     not be resolved to an installable set of dependencies, or a
 !     platform package repository was unreachable.
 !     
 !     This usually means that you (or packages you are using) depend
 !     on a combination of PHP versions and/or extensions that are
 !     currently not available on Heroku.
 !     
 !     The following is the full output from the installation attempt:
 !     
 !     > Loading repositories with available runtimes and extensions
 !     > Updating dependencies
 !     > Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.
 !     > 
 !     >   Problem 1
 !     >     - composer.json/composer.lock requires ext-enchant ^7.2 -> no matching package found.
 !     > 
 !     
 !     For reference, the following runtimes are currently available:
 !     
 !     PHP:  7.3.11, 7.3.10, 7.3.9, 7.3.8, 7.3.7, 7.3.6, 7.3.5, 7.3.4, 
 !     7.3.3, 7.3.2, 7.3.1, 7.3.0, 7.2.24, 7.2.23, 7.2.22, 
 !     7.2.21, 7.2.20, 7.2.19, 7.2.18, 7.2.17, 7.2.16, 7.2.15, 
 !     7.2.14, 7.2.13, 7.1.33, 7.1.32, 7.1.31, 7.1.30, 7.1.29, 
 !     7.1.28, 7.1.27, 7.1.26, 7.1.25
 !     HHVM: 
 !     
 !     Please verify that all requirements for runtime versions in
 !     'composer.lock' are compatible with the list above, and ensure
 !     all required extensions are available for the desired runtimes.
 !     
 !     When choosing a PHP runtimes and extensions, please also ensure
 !     they are available on your app's stack (heroku-18), and select
 !     a different stack if needed after consulting the article below.
 !     
 !     Be advised that the heroku-18 stack you're currently using only
 !     supports PHP version 7.1 and later.
 !     
 !     For a list of supported runtimes & extensions on Heroku, please
 !     refer to: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/php-support
 !     
 !     REMINDER: the following warnings were emitted during the build;
 !     check the details above, as they may be related to this error:
 !     - A requested extension is not available
 !     Push rejected, failed to compile PHP app.
 !     Push failed
```

I've search for days no result. Any help would be much appreciated.